# Finding a Column in File1 present in File2 in awk

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I've 2 files as below

```
File1
USA,China,India,Canada

File2
Iran|XXXXXX|Iranian
Iraq|YYYYYY|Iraquian
Saudi|ZZZZZ|Saudi is a Rich Country
USA|AAAAAA|USA is United States of America.
India|IIII|India got freedom from British.
Scot|SSSSS|Canada Mexio.
```

How can I read the Value in File1 and check if it matches with the first delimited string in File2 using awk? I've tried this But i could not achieve it. Please help.

For the Above Input the Output should be

```
USA Matches
China Not Matched
India Matches
Canada Not Matches
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a){print $i,"Matches"} else {print $i,"Not Matches."}}}' FS="|" Input_file2 FS="," Input_file1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl also

```
$ cat vinoth1
USA,China,India,Canada
$ cat vinoth2
Iran|XXXXXX|Iranian
Iraq|YYYYYY|Iraquian
Saudi|ZZZZZ|Saudi is a Rich Country
USA|AAAAAA|USA is United States of America.
India|IIII|India got freedom from British.
Scot|SSSSS|Canada Mexio.
$ perl -F, -lane ' BEGIN { $x=qx(cat vinoth2) } print $_,$x=~/^$_/m ? " matches" : " not matches" for(@F) ' vinoth1
USA matches
China not matches
India matches
Canada not matches
```